# Does the output depend on the compiler?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a code. The code prints `1236` (g++ 7.5.0)

Does the output depend on the compiler? (e.g. output can be `3216`)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


using namespace std;


int foo(int& x) {
    std::cout << ++x; 
    return x;
}


int main() {
    int i = 0;
    cout << foo(i) + foo(i) + foo(i) << endl; // 1236
}
```

Comment: already the first line is non portable C++. Others compiler may not even compile this

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "Don't". Other compilers *don't* compile this. No "may" about it. MSVC in particular.

Comment: @Casey what I said. Other compilers may compile it or may not compile it. It is non standard

Comment: Regarding `foo(i) + foo(i) + foo(i)` part specifically; I believe it's portable. The order of evaluation of the three `foo` calls is unspecified, but the code is arranged so that it produces the same outcome regardless of that order. The three calls are equivalent, so it doesn't matter which one goes first, or second.

Comment: @Casey Nitpick: there is more than one compiler that can compile this (GCC and Clang when it uses libstdc++). So 463035818_is_not_a_number is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the output **does not depend** on the compiler (modulo the `bits/stdc++.h` nonsense).  The order in which the three calls `foo(i)` are evaluated is unspecified, but that doesn't affect the output: function calls are not interleaved, so *some* call will increment `i` to 1, print that, and return it (as a **copy**), then one of the other two will assign, print, and return 2, then the last will do 3, and their return values will always sum to 6.

Note that if `foo` returned **`int&`**, the last output might be any digit 6–9, since the implementation might not choose to read `i` for the addition immediately upon return.  The behavior would still be defined, though, since those reads would be **indeterminately sequenced** with respect to any write.